# Cordova-Cloudinadinary plugin command

Tags: cordova, plugins, command, cloudinary

I was try to add plugin for cordova-cloudinary through following command and not support.Kindly update the command for add cloudinary plugin in cordova web site.

cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.cloudinary

but it shows the error. 404not found.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the plugin you referred to.
If you refer to https://github.com/collectmeaustralia/cordova-cloudinary-upload, then they have specific instructions on how to install their plugin.